# Xcode files disappear from project navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I'm running into a strange Xcode issue where files that match my search are disappearing from the project navigator.  With only 1 tab open in Xcode, I type a few letters into the search box in the project navigator.  The list of files immediately filters to match my search term.

I then do nothing, and wait for 5 seconds, and Xcode refreshes and the files disappear and it displays "No Filter Results".  If I add or remove a letter from the search box, the files come back for a few seconds, but then they disappear again.  Is this some Xcode glitch? Or do I have to change something to get my files to stop disappearing when I do a search. I am on Xcode 7.3.1.

None of my other navigator tabs have any text in the search boxes. I also do not have the 'source control' or 'recent files' filters selected, as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have XCode 7.3.1 but cannot reproduce the behavior you are seeing. Please check following - there is filter box at the bottom, make sure that nothing there. If that does not resolve the problem check your settings in Xcode->Preferences->general->Find Navigator Details. Also try reinstalling xcode.

Comment: The filter box is pictured in the screenshot I attached.  It is partially filled with my search term.  I know there are 4-5 files that match the search term, as they are the ones that show briefly before disappearing.  I guess I'll try  reinstalling xcode next.